# PHP parsing .txt file into an array witha specific start and end

Tags: php

Okay, i've read a lot of information on parsing a .TXT file. but I cant seem to work this one out.Ultimately i need to parse the data from a .txt file into an array starting after a specific line that says '!data;' and stopping at '!enddata;' below is the example of my source file. I want to pick out all of the data separated by the colon and place it into an array. if you can give me some asssistance; or point me in the right direction, that would be awesome :)

```
Usless text
!data;
data1:data2:data3:data4:data5:data6:data7:
data1:data2:data3:data4:data5:data6:data7:

!enddata;
More Useless text
```

i know on each line i need to use the explode function, i just dont know how to get it to start stop at that specific line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't necessary. Use [`file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to split a file into an array of lines, and create a boolean value (here, `$capture`) to "remember" whether future lines should be captured or not.

```
$lines = file('example.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$start_identifier = '!data;';
$end_identifier = '!enddata;';
$capture = false;
$elements = array();

foreach($lines as $line){
    // Capture subsequent lines, skip this line which doesn't contain data
    if($line == $start_identifier){
        $capture = true;
        continue;
    }
    // Skip subsequent lines, skip this line which doesn't contain data
    elseif($line == $end_identifier){
        $capture = false;
        continue;
    }

    // If we should capture this line, implement splitting logic to do so
    if($capture and !empty($line)){
        // Split elements of this line
        $line_elements = explode(':', $line);
        // Remove empty elements
        $line_elements = array_filter($line_elements, function($e){ return !empty($e); });
        // Add this line's elements to array of all elements
        $elements = array_merge($elements, $line_elements);
    }
}

$elements; // array('data1', 'data2', ...
```

Comment: This answer helped me the most and modeled (in a cleaner way) the path that i was going down. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this using `array_slice` and `file` in PHP

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$arr=file('status.txt'); //<---- Grabbing all the content to an array 
$arr = array_map('trim',$arr);
$keyStart = array_search(trim('!data;'),$arr);   //<----- Beginning Key
$keyEnd=array_search('!enddata;',$arr);          //<----- Ending key
$output = array_slice($arr, $keyStart, $keyEnd); // Use slice to extract portion !
print_r($output);                                // Print your results !
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => !data;
    [1] => data1:data2:data3:data4:data5:data6:data7:
    [2] => data1:data2:data3:data4:data5:data6:data7:
    [3] => 
    [4] => !enddata;
)
```

Comment: Great Answer Shankar!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this with regex.

Our plan of attack:

1. strip everything before '!data;' and everything after '!enddata;'
2. remove all newline characters
3. explode on ':'

   ```
   $file = file_get_contents('data.txt');
   $file = preg_replace('/.*!data;/ms', '', $file);
   $file = preg_replace('/!enddata;.*$/ms', '', $file);

   $file = preg_replace('/\r\n/', '', $file);

   $result = explode(':', $file);
   ```

Explanations:
The m modifier lets it match on multiline strings.

The s modifier (dotall) lets . match newline characters

\r\n handles windows type newlines. You can change that to just \n on linux (or do both types to handle both types)

Finally, explode splits on ':' character.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
$temp ="";
$i=0;
$handle = @fopen("text.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
            $temp = $temp . $buffer;
            if(strpos($temp,"!enddata;") === false){
            if (strpos($temp,'!data;') !== false) {
               $arr[$i] =  $buffer;
            }
            $i++;
        }   
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: `while(strpos($temp,'!enddata') !== true)` is an infinite loop. [`strpos`](http://us1.php.net/strpos) never returns `true`.